# Screen flickers (radeon)

Tags: ati, radeon

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 and open-source AMD drivers. My monitor flickers when I open some windows (for example, system settings). I have just come from Windows and I need your help, guys.
Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1AWLn9bNis (at 0:05)

P.S. Sorry for my English, I am from Russia :)

Comment: What do you mean by "installed open-source drivers"? What is your video card?

Comment: It means that I do not have proprietary drivers installed. My graphics card is ATI Radeon 4850.